# skb_header_pointer() always returns in big-endian?

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, endianness

The Linux kernel defines this API:

```
static inline void * __must_check
__skb_header_pointer(const struct sk_buff *skb, int offset,
             int len, void *data, int hlen, void *buffer)
{
    if (hlen - offset >= len)
        return data + offset;

    if (!skb ||
        skb_copy_bits(skb, offset, buffer, len) < 0)
        return NULL;

    return buffer;
}

static inline void * __must_check
skb_header_pointer(const struct sk_buff *skb, int offset, int len, void *buffer)
{
    return __skb_header_pointer(skb, offset, len, skb->data,
                    skb_headlen(skb), buffer);
}
```

In some parts of the kernel this API is used to retrieve packet fields in big-endian since it is a network `skb`. So I understand when this API is applied to packet headers, which we know have some fields in big-endian, e.g. `struct iphdr` where 16/32-bit fields are explicitly declared as `__be16/__be32`.

So according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

> fields in the protocols of the Internet protocol suite, such as IPv4, IPv6, TCP, and UDP, are transmitted in big-endian order.

However, is it always guaranteed that *any* 16- or 32-bit portion of the packet stored in `skb` will be in network-byte order?

So in other words, the following call:

```
u32 *ptr, data;
ptr = skb_header_pointer(skb, offset, 4, &data);
```

could be changed to:

```
__be32 *ptr, data;
ptr = skb_header_pointer(skb, offset, 4, &data);
```

Is this right assumption?

**UPDATE** I think it is not. Only the protocol (IP/TCP/UDP/ICMP/etc.) headers are required to be in big-endian byte order, the payload byte order is determined by sending machine.

Comment: How endiannes of the value of pointer to the data related to the endianess of data itself?

Comment: This is to _indicate_ that the memory at the pointer has bytes in big-endian order.

Comment: the data itself is a payload as byte array, it has no endianess property at all.